# Running Script on page load in google-amp and to be validated as amp-page

Tags: amp-html

I want to check my app login state. Want to do some api calls if it is logged in and conditionally rendering my home page based on the state and also it should be validated as an amp page.Is there some work around to achieve this?.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no workaround needed. You can use the amp-access component ([doc](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-access/?format=websites) / [sample](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-access/)) for this purpose. It also supports [OAuth2 based login flows](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/personalization/oauth2_login/).